# Add a parameter to an existing Func

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, func, insight.database

It's a bit tricky question and I don't know if it's possible.

Let's say that I have a class `Foo1` that's in a DLL and I can't modify it. The class looks like this:

```
public class Foo1<T1> : IFoo<T1>
{
    public Foo1(Func<IFoo, T1, T1> postRead);
}
```

I want to inherit `Foo1` and be able to inject a `T2` object in the original `postRead` and access it in the base `postRead`.

Something like this:

```
public class Foo2<T1, T2> : Foo<T1>
{
    public Foo2(Func<IFoo, T1, T2, T1> newPostRead)
        :base(Func<IFoo, T1, T1> secondPostRead)
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
I'm using [insight DB](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database). It's an ORM. There's feature that does post processing. The code looks like this:

```
public class PostProcessRecordReader<T> : RecordReader<T>
{
    public PostProcessRecordReader(Func<IDataReader, T, T> postRead);
}

//How to use the processor 
public DummyFunction(ObjectIWantToUse objectIwantToUse)
{
    PostProcessRecordReader<Foo> _postProcessorForCubeWithAllEntitiesForBuilding = new PostProcessRecordReader<Foo> (reader, obj) =>
        {
            //Need to have access objectIwantToUse !!!


            //maybe I want to modify obj or add some stuff to it
        }
    );
    //Do some stuff by using _postProcessorForCubeWithAllEntitiesForBuilding
}
```

We can do some processing on the object once returned from the DB, by accessing directly the reader.

Comment: It's hard to know what you want to do with the extra parameter... can you give a concrete example?

Comment: The answer could be yes, but you need to provide one extra piece of information: what's supposed to happen with the newly introduced `T2`?

Comment: Please provide code that actually compiles

Comment: I did an edit of my question.

Answer (score -1):

`Foo1<T1>` takes a function that has two `T1` parameters and returns an `IFoo<T1>`.  I presums that `Foo1` *calls* that function at some point.

You are wanting to pass it a function that takes two `T1` parameters *and* a `T2` parameter.  The problem is - `Foo1` knows *nothing* about `T2` - so how is it supposed to know what to pass in?

Now `Foo2` knows about `T2` but has to pass that information on to T1 somehow.  It *could* map the original function to one with less parameters, but it would have to have some sort of resolver that knows what `T2` should be:

```
public class Foo2<T1, T2> : Foo1<T1>
{
    public Foo2(Func<IFoo<T1>, T1, T2, T1> newPostRead, Func<T2> resolver)
        :base((IFoo<T1> t1a, T1 t1b) => newPostRead(t1a, t1b, resolver() ))
    {
    }
}
```

It will at least *compile*, but it's not clear from your description if this is a viable solution.

Comment: in fact Foo1<T1> take a reader and T1 and returns T1. I want to let the base class to know T2, so I can use it, like I showed in the edited question.